# Query multiple columns in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have products as columns and companies as rows, the selections are shown with the checkboxes.

[sheet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx0wC.png)

However I am not interested in querying companies, I want to query and count the products selections and display them like this:

[query result setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d1Ct.png)

What query formula should I used for this?

Comment: Yes, I need to count how many of each products were selected

Comment: Ok i got it take a look

Comment: Exact copy of [Query multiple columns in Google Sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/172417228) that also has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Try this, look at this [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m5V0FMr9qQXrZR2kY8951kTFwJFAqVrwvFfxJINRZfU/edit?usp=sharing)

> **Paste** this formula next to products name and drag down.

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER($B$2:$L$16,$B$1:$L$1=N2),TRUE)
```

[image]

### Explanation

[`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) the range `$B$2:$L$16` where the headers `$L$1` = the value in range `N2:N12` products, the output is TRUE and FALSE Array.

count TRUE value in the Array resulted from [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) with [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) function [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)[`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)`[ True / false array ], TRUE` TRUE is [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) criterion.

### From another tab

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(Selections!$B$2:$L$16,Selections!$B$1:$L$1=B2),TRUE)
```

[image]

At a glance
[image]

---

A tweek on [*player0*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102609/19529694) **keep ranges open** to add more values

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FLATTEN(Selections!B1:L1), 
 FLATTEN(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Selections!B2:L*1), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(Selections!B2:B), 1, 1, 0)))})
```

Comment: Mmmh this makes sense however my dataset is in one sheet but I want to display the results in a different one: I tried this =COUNTIF(Selections!FILTER(C4:N17,C3:N3),TRUE) but it won't work.

Comment: @Pastille: You should define your problem in the main text of your question. Not in comment to an answer after the fact

Comment: As @Argyll stated take a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help the respondents solve the question seamlessly. he may took the time to answer you question an suddenly faced with a diffrent ask.

Comment: @Argyll Sorry! I thought I knew how to format for that case, but apparently I needed some help there as well!

Comment: @Osm Thank you! I understand there is no need to use query for this simple task :)

Comment: @osm I need reputation for that :/ I got no street cred

Comment: @Pastille: It's still good to edit the full requirements into your question now. So that the Q&A can be of use for other users. (Ofc, every time you edit your question significantly -- ideally you don't, you should communicate to existing answerers first. That you already did.)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FLATTEN(Selections!B1:L1), 
 FLATTEN(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Selections!B2:L16*1), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(Selections!B2:B16), 1, 1, 0)))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the selection of prod 01 always reside in B2:B, why not just `countif(B2:B, true)` for prod 01?

For a spread-able formula, we note that you need the column index to iterate over different prod ##, but you want a summary table that is vertical. You can use `indirect()` to accomplish "transposed" iteration as follows. In the A1 of your other sheet, you can put

```
=countif(indirect("Sheet1!R2C"&(row(A1)-row(A$1)+1)&":C"&(row(A1)-row(A$1)+1),false),false)
```

And you can spread vertically for the formula to retrieve counts in the subsequent columns in Sheet1.

If you move the starting cell of your summary table elsewhere, you should replace `A1`, `A$1` in the above formula to the corresponding cell name.

---

The benefit of the above formula is that you are not scanning your data range unnecessarily.

Since we are mutating the formula in place, we only apply `countif()` to one specified column of your data at a time. For an m-by-n array, you are only doing atomic computations ~m*n times.

If you `filter()` your whole range per row, you multiple the amount of computations by n-fold.

If you centralize your formula by using `mmult()`, you multiply the amount of computations by m*n-fold -- squaring the original demand (and then scaled by a constant factor). With that, your sheet will be impractically slow way sooner than you may expect with mere a few thousand entries. Memory access would contribute to the run time delay.

Whenever you are handling a large database, only simplify your formula sparingly and cautiously.